# iPhone: How do I change the default start time of an event?

Tags: iphone, calendar, ical

Often I find myself finishing a meeting and setting up one the following week, same time same place.  Apple is pretty good about suggesting the place and even autocompleteing the title, but the time is almost always very close to the current time, NOT the time of event I am copying.

Is there any way to make this a little more "dumb" and just grab the previous event's time instead of assuming that I want the current time?  This would also make it much easier to paste events that repeat irregularly.

Comment: Are you doing this in the Apple Calendar.app?

Comment: Yes, I am doing it in the app.

Answer (score 1):

Using Siri let’s you nail the start time. The system does still prefer to make a new appointment now if you don’t specify the start time or a start day.

> Hey Siri, make an appointment for 10 am next Tuesday.

Also, for when the default calendar is lacking, you can get some very capable apps to extend how you view, automate and combine calendars if you don’t want to just add all your calendars to the native iOS settings and use Siri / calendar.app - the first two I recommend are:

- [Fantastical 2](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/fantastical-2-for-ipad/id830708155) - a powerhouse of intelligence and smart scheduling
- [Calendars 5](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/calendars-5-by-readdle/id697927927) - also has better smart scheduling than iOS and has great integration for google calendars and other cloud calendars.

You don’t need another app, though to just make an appointment precisely when you want it to be slotted in your calendar, just use alternate input mechanisms. These third-party apps had smart scheduling before iOS implemented it, but now Apple ships everything you need so only get these if you need more than one Apple can do out of the box.