# Mojave: Default start time of new events

Tags: mojave, calendar

When I create a new event in Calendar, it starts at 9:00 am and ends at 10:00 am. I want to change that to one hour earlier. Is there a way to achieve this?

I know there's a way to change the default duration of new events and it's not what I'm looking for. I found [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/366582/iphone-how-do-i-change-the-default-start-time-of-an-event) question without an answer for the iPhone. I'm on macOS 10.14.6.

Comment: Precisely how are you creating the events? The language processing is really slick to pick the start time, so I'm not even clear my answer will help if you're locked into a specific way to create events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose the time to start / end your day with macOS Calendar - it's in the general setting.

[image: Calendar app preferences]

For specific events, Calendar app should do natural language scheduling like many third party calendar apps have done for quite some time.

- https://flexibits.com/fantastical

Fantasitcal has a free trail and is worth every penny in my experience, but you can use native new event controls to just make your appoint for the date and time of your chosing. Siri will do this as well for you, you just need to be in a place where you feel comfortable speaking to your Mac and enable Siri.

> Make an appointment for next Wednesday at 11 am

[image: Apple Calendar new event language processing interface]

And with the text above, you should see this completion (for the next few days at least when another next Wednesday will be selected).

[image: Apple Calendar new event language processing results]

Comment: I guess it answers my question. I create many calendar entries for upcoming days at 8:00am. I asked for a default because I don't want to say (in which way ever) that it has to be at 8:00am instead of 9:00am every time. Maybe I was just a little bit too lazy. Both the typing and the speaking work perfectly. Thanks for the answer. I checked Fantastical and it seems that it has a lot to offer, and I might test it.

Comment: @StefanBerger Did you change the start time in Calendar preferences? See my edit.

Comment: Yes, i tried that too. It was actually set to 8:00 already and i changed it to 7:00. It didn't seem to change anything. I read somewhere that that's only relevant for notifications when to start to be on time at the given place of the appointment.